# Undefined variable: annonces (View: D:\wamp\www\aswak\resources\views\annonces\details.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

i want to display annn images from id pass in Annoncescontroller to blade details uses laravel 6 but it gives me error Undefined variable: annonces (View: D: \ wamp \ www \ aswak \ resources \ views \ adverts \ details. blade.php)

AnnoncesController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
     return view('annonces.details', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

details.blade.php

```
<div class="product-section container">
    <div>
        <div class="product-section-image">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$annonces->image) }}" alt="product" class="active" id="currentImage">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end product-section -->
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('annonces','AnnoncesController');
```

Comment: you are passing `id` to your view, not `annonces` and you are also not passing a model (it would seem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's what you define in the view method that comes to the blade component as a variable.

AnnoncesController.php

```
return view('annonces.details', ['id' => $id]);
```

details.blade.php

```
{{ id }}
```

---

So if you want `$annonces->image` then you gotta pass that too, inside the view method.

AnnoncesController.php

```
return view('annonces.details', ['id' => $id, 'announces' => $announces]);
```